# Can I control which nuke will be launched?

Tags: starcraft-2

Assuming I have multiple nukes ready at different ghost academies, when I launch a nuke, which one will be used? There are times when I want to choose the nuke to use, for example during a base race where I'd like to use the ghost academy that will be killed first.

Comment: Maybe you could make a suggestion for Blizzard to change that. Still this is only significant if the silos are in 2 different locations (e.g. main base and 4th base). But I doubt they will fix it, because there are so few scenarios that will profit from this. You need to be in a base race scenario and have multiple nukes in different places. Thats like 1 out of 1000 games, and that is even a generous estimation. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no way to choose your nuke. They are launched in sequence. Meaning the nuke you build first gets shoot first.

This means you can choose the order before you build them, but you cannot change it afterwards.

Source: I opened a game, build 2 silos and tried everything to change the order. There just is no UI to change the order. I even tried to select 1 Ghost and 1 Silo while launching, still no effect.

Comment: Did you check if maybe the distances matters, i.e. closest nuke gets launched first?

Comment: Yeah it does not matter. Another bonus I found during this is that you can cancel the nuke with ESC as long as you see the red dot.

Comment: Cancelling a launched nuke won't put it back in the silo. It won't land either, so I guess it just floats around space for all time.

Comment: That is correct but you can use it to gain a better position. If your opponent has sieged you can use a nuke to force him unsieging his tanks. Either he stays and dies from the nuke or he unsieges, you cancel the nuke and stim into his tanks. I knew it is possible to cancel nukes, but not up to which point. Well now I know :)